# iOS - UITableView Cell not touchable

Tags: ios, uitableview

Quick question, I'm creating a custom popup within a UIView with a UIImageView as the background and a UITableView overlaying on top. It has three cells, but for some reason the bottom two cells are clickable but the top one isn't. When I NSLog the touch this is what i get:

```
touching <UIView: 0xa3d0200; frame = (0 0; 320 460); autoresize = W+H; tag = 333; layer = <CALayer: 0xa3d0260>>
```

It says it touching self.view. any ideas?

Comment: What are your cells like? Are they static, or Dynamic prototypes?

Comment: dynamic prototypes. each cell has 1 label in it essentially.

Comment: OK, OK. Can you post the code where you are creating them (i.e. the `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` methods?)

Comment: It could be that the top of the table view is outside the bounds of its superview. Set clipsToBounds to YES for its superview, and see if part of the table disappears.

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"OptionsCell";
    OptionsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OptionsCell" owner:self options:NULL];
        cell = (OptionsCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    
    cell.cellTitle.text = [self.optionsData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    
    return cell;
}

Comment: Woah. Next time, you can edit your question and post code there:) Anyways, have you tried looking into @rdelmar suggestion?

Comment: ya i did and it clips the top part of the view. I looks like the superview it smaller then the table which i don't understand why. In the interface builder, everything looks perfect and on the iPhone 5 it looks perfect too just on the other devices/simulators with the smaller resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I just had to make the superview a little bit larger and everything was working as expected.